# Program that should output nth arrangement of paintings

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently practicing for the British informatics olympiad by doing past papers.

I'm on question 3 of [the 2015 paper](http://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2015/bio/bio15-exam.pdf) and trying to use recursion to solve it. I'm pretty new to using recursion but I'm not sure what I can do to make my recursive function any more efficient.

The program runs fine for [the smaller test numbers](http://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2015/bio/bio15-marks.pdf) but for larger ones my program takes upwards of 5 seconds, when it should take 1 second max.

I don't want you to fix my code for me (this is a past question so doing that is pointless), what I want to know is: where I am going wrong with my recursive function and how I can use recursion or similar problem solving techniques in the future more efficiently.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm going to be doing the test tomorrow!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q3_2015 {

    static ArrayList<String> works = new ArrayList<String>();
    //static ArrayList<String> allWorks = new ArrayList<String>(); //used for question 2
    static int counter = 0;
    static String currentFinishedWork;
    static int a;
    static int b;
    static int c;
    static int d;
    static int n;
    static boolean fullwork;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
        c = scan.nextInt();
        d = scan.nextInt();
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (int aAmount = 0; aAmount < a; aAmount++) {

            works.add("A");
        }

        for (int bAmount = 0; bAmount < b; bAmount++) {

            works.add("B");
        }

        for (int cAmount = 0; cAmount < c; cAmount++) {

            works.add("C");
        }

        for (int dAmount = 0; dAmount < d; dAmount++) {

            works.add("D");
        }



        //System.out.println(works);

        WorksSolver("");

        //System.out.println(allWorks); //used for question 2
        System.out.println(currentFinishedWork);



    }

    public static void WorksSolver (String currentWork) {//, int aWorksLeft, int bWorksLeft, int cWorksLeft, int dWorksLeft) {

        if (counter == n) {//allWorks.size() == n) { //used for question 2

            //System.out.println("hhee");
            return;
        }

        fullwork = true;

        if (currentWork.length() - currentWork.replaceAll("A", "").length() < a) {

            fullwork = false;
            WorksSolver(currentWork + "A");
        }

        if (currentWork.length() - currentWork.replaceAll("B", "").length() < b) {

            fullwork = false;
            WorksSolver(currentWork + "B");
        }

        if (currentWork.length() - currentWork.replaceAll("C", "").length() < c) {

            fullwork = false;
            WorksSolver(currentWork + "C");
        }

        if (currentWork.length() - currentWork.replaceAll("D", "").length() < d) {

            fullwork = false;
            WorksSolver(currentWork + "D");
        }

        if (fullwork) {

            currentFinishedWork = currentWork;
            counter ++;
            //allWorks.add(currentWork); //used for question 2
        }


        //if (aWorksLeft == 0 && bWorksLeft == 0 && cWorksLeft == 0 && dWorksLeft == 0) {
    //}


    }
}
```

Comment: QuickComment: Don't use String manipulation because it is really slow! You can use a Array/List of integers or characters, that will speed thing up a lot.

Comment: RobAu thanks, I'll make sure to try this later on

Comment: The approach by @Sharon is correct. Use combinatorics (a+b+c...)!/(a!b!c!...) to calculate the combination possible. If you like, I have a working implementation that runs in O(n)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please read (and follow) the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: @RobAu that would be great, I know combinatorics can really help with a lot of the Olympiad questions but I'm finding it really tough to put the formulas into practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major bug number 1: `fullwork` should not be a field from the class. It should be a local variable in the method.

---

With that out of the way let's look at what's taking so long.
The main reason is how you check if there's still a certain "Work" left to add.
By doing `currentWork.replaceAll("A", "")` you're running over `currentWork` entirely and replace each occurence of `A` creating a new String. This would be at best O(N) where N is the length of the `currentWork` String.
<del>Assuming your recursion runs O(N²) times (roughly the number of ways to combine N works, it's actually less since you don't swap works from the same author). This means that the actual time for your implementation is O(N³) (note, it might be O(n^4) depending on how bad `replaceAll()` is ... not sure myself).</del>
Edit: There's way more than O(N²) ways to combine N works. The main point stays the same, but the result is even worse...

So how do we get rid of it?

You already had part of the solution in a comment. Pass on the remaining number of A, B, C and D to the method and check if it is `> 0` to know if you can add one more to the `currentWorrk` or not.

The part you're missing is how to do the recursive call. But this is actually pretty easy. Just call it with the same numbers but reduce the `aWorksLeft` by 1 if you added an A. Or the `bWorksLeft` if you added a B etc...

```
if (aWorksLeft > 0) {
    findNthArrangement(currentWork + "A", aWorksLeft - 1, bWorksLeft, cWorksLeft, dWorksLeft);
}
```

This change alone reduced the time for the 7th test from over 6 seconds to 0.1 seconds on my machine.

Great, one more point :)

But from here on out it'll be hard to really get the time down. I tried to make use of a better data structure to pass the `currentWork` since string concatenation is somewhat expensive. Using a char array instead, I could get the time for the 8th test down from 6s to 3.7s.

```
public static void findNthArrangement(char[] currentWork, int currentPosition, int aWorksLeft, int bWorksLeft, int cWorksLeft, int dWorksLeft) {
    if (counter == n) {//allWorks.size() == n) { //used for question 2
        return;
    }

    if (aWorksLeft == 0 && bWorksLeft == 0 && cWorksLeft == 0 && dWorksLeft == 0) {
        currentFinishedWork = new String(currentWork);
        counter ++;
        return;
    }

    if (aWorksLeft > 0) {
        currentWork[currentPosition] = 'A';
        findNthArrangement(currentWork, currentPosition +1, aWorksLeft - 1, bWorksLeft, cWorksLeft, dWorksLeft);
    }

    //similar for B, C and D
}
```

The problem is that you're not really going to get the time down further than this with a solution that actually generates all possible configurations (up to the nth). In order to get the time down under 1s even for the most difficult tests, you'll have to come up with a formula that allows you to skip most of the work, like Sharon Ben Asher suggests in his answer.

---

#### Conclusion

- You got the basic idea behind recursion right but could use some more experience to see which parameters to pass on to the next step.
- Java String manipulation is really expensive. You can get a major speed up if it's possible to avoid it.
- Java doesn't optimise recursive calls at all. Look for alternative solutions if speed/memory are an issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain to me, I was really afraid to pass too many parameters to the function as I've had stack overflow errors from using too many but I didn't realize that replacing parameters with calculations would cause so much of a decrease in performance. I had seen that iteration was usually better than recursion if it's possible to use it and a solution with neither (like Ben Asher's suggestion) can be even better, I'll try to solve problems with the best performance options first before I just dive right in with recursion. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

I have thought of the following algorithm that is NOT recursive at all and thus has linear \$o(n)\$ complexity (n being the total number of works meaning a+b+c+d+e...):

The order of arrangements in the list is alphabetical.  This means that the list will forever begin with arrangements beginning with A and then arrangements beginning with B and so on. So looking at the example list in the question, the first **column** of letters shows consecutive ranges of letters: AAABBBBBBCCC. You can calculate this "list of first letters" based on the input values of how many artists and how many works for each artist (I will let you figure out the exact formula, its pretty easy). So now you can determine the first letter of the n<sup>th</sup> arrangement directly from this formula.

Once you have that, it's pretty easy to calculate the rest of the letters by removing the first letter and applying the formula as if the input was one work less.

Comment: Although you clearly know what should be done to solve the original problem and your answer gives a hint at how to get there, it doesn't actually review the current code. The minimal extra information I would expect is WHY the current recursion is a bad idea. Since that would give a good reason to discard the current implementation for something else.

Comment: I thought I did give the reason why recursion is a bad idea - performance, which is the concern of OP.

Answer (score 1):

While generating all the individual pieces will work, it will get slow really fast, as you experienced yourself. @Sharon already described the start of the solution, I will try to explain a bit more.

Consider AABB and n=10. The list is sorted, so you know the number of combination starting with A is the number of unique arrangements of the remaining ABB.

The number of permutations of length n = n!, so of ABB = n!. But because we need the unique arrangements, we need to divide by all the possible arrangements of the letter A, and B. So the number of arrangments of ABB will become  `#(As+Bs)! / #As!*#Bs!` => `3! / 1!*2!` = `6 / 2 = 3`. Indeed, `ABB`, `BAB` and `BBA`.

So, in order to get the nth arrangement of paintings, start by checking if the arrangement starts with A (we have 6 of them). If `n>6`, we know we can skip all arrangements and start checking the arrangements that start with B. Because we skipped 6, we need to find the 4th arrangement that starts with B.

There are 6 arrangements that start with B, we need to find the 4th. So we recurse and try to find the 4th arrangement of `AAB`. We can start over again.

We only need to store the number of occurances of each letter, so for example our `AABB` becomes `int[] {2,2}`.

We need some helpers:

```
public static long factorial(int n) {
    long fac = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fac *= i;
    }
    return fac;
}

public static final long combisOfOccurenes(int[] ints) {
    int sum = Arrays.stream(ints).sum();
    int div = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        div *= factorial(ints[i]);
    }
    return factorial(sum) / div;
}
```

Note that the `combisOfOccurences` can be made more efficient by refactoring out the common factors before the division, but I did not need that in the examples provided.

Now you need only to find the recursive function that handles the algorithm above :)

SPOILER:

> public static String findNthOccurance0Based(int[] occurences, long index) {
>       System.out.println("Finding nth occurance:" + index + " in " + getNiceString(occurences));
>       if (index == 0) // if we need the 0th index, we just return the occurrences string
>           return getString(occurences);
>       else {
>           int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(occurences, occurences.length);
>           long newN = index;
>           int indexOfCurrentOccurence = 0;
>           while (indexOfCurrentOccurence < occurences.length) {
>               if (copy[indexOfCurrentOccurence] == 0) {
>                   indexOfCurrentOccurence++;
>                   continue;
>               }
>               // remove first occurence
>               copy[indexOfCurrentOccurence]--;
>               long combis = combisOfOccurenes(copy);
>               System.out.println(
>                       "Found " + combis + " combinations for " + getNiceString(indexOfCurrentOccurence, copy));
>               System.out.println("newN = " + newN + " combis =" + combis);
>               // if we found 500 combinations, and we need the 400th, we take the 'A' and find
>               // the 400 in the sub.
>               if (newN < combis) {
>                   System.out.println("There are enough combination with this starting letter");
>                   // combis > n,
>                   return getChar(indexOfCurrentOccurence) + findNthOccurance0Based(copy, newN);
>               } else {
>                   newN -= combis;
>                   // restore the current occurenceindedx and skip to the next index.
>                   copy[indexOfCurrentOccurence]++;
>                   indexOfCurrentOccurence++;
>               }
>           }
>           throw new RuntimeException("Oout of bounds");
>       }
>   }

Comment: This is great, I saw an example of this solution in python which used the permutafion formula but it wasn't obvious how it related to the rest of the program. I'm definately going to have to practise to be able to see where I can use shortcuts like this in a program challenge but this will help a lot.

Comment: Nice complementary answer to mine explaining how to solve the original problem. I didn't take the time to add this to my answer since the intention of the question was to get a better idea of how and when to use recursion in general. Have an upvote :)